# Read formatted text file into array list JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stream

I need my java program to read a formatted text file, I'll give an example of how it's formatted

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB383.png

So the #1 is the number of countries listed, the A is the zone, and New Zealand is the country.

So I know that I need to read the number after # and that's how many times to run the loop, then the next line contains the zone name which will be the name of the array list. But as for actually achieving this I'm super lost.

Currently my code looks like this,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class destination{

    String zone;
    ArrayList<String> countries;

    public Object destinationList(){

        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("Files/Destination.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            destinations.add(s.nextLine());

        }
        s.close();

        int sz = destinations.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            System.out.println(destinations.get(i).toString());
        }

        return destinations;
    }

}
```

But this just dumps the text file into an array list

Comment: Post at least a couple of lines of your text file in the question and add expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need extra class with zone and countries, it will work perfect with Map:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> destinations = new HashMap<>();
```

To fill the map with values from file, you can write something like (not tested).

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Files/Destination.txt"));
int currentCount = 0;
String currentZone = "";
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("#") { // number of countries
        currentCount = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1));
    } else if (line.length() == 1) { // zone
        currentZone = line;
        destinations.put(currentZone, new ArrayList<String>(currentCount);
    } else { // add country to current zone
        destinations.get(currentZone).add(line);
    }
}
```